# Serializable not sending putExtra in intent

Tags: android, android-intent

Why is my putExtra in my intent is not working no values are being passed in the intent. All of the values are being present on the listview but when I click an item on the listview when I'm going to the `DetailActivity` there are no values now. Thanks in advance for the answer.

## Main Acitivty

```
    @Override
public void processFinish(String s) {
    Log.d(TAG,s);

    carList = new JsonConverter<Cars>().toArrayList(s, Cars.class);

    BindDictionary<Cars> dict = new BindDictionary<Cars>();
    dict.addDynamicImageField(R.id.ivImg1, new StringExtractor<Cars>() {
        @Override
        public String getStringValue(Cars product, int position) {
            return product.Image;
        }
    }, new DynamicImageLoader() {
        @Override

        public void loadImage(String url, ImageView imageView) {

            ImageLoader.getInstance().displayImage(url, imageView); // Default options will be used

        }
    });
    dict.addStringField(R.id.tvCarModel, new StringExtractor<Cars>() {
        @Override
        public String getStringValue(Cars product, int position) {
            return "Car Model: " + product.Car_Model;
        }
    });
    dict.addStringField(R.id.carID, new StringExtractor<Cars>() {
        @Override
        public String getStringValue(Cars product, int position) {
            return ""+product.Car_No;
        }
    });
    dict.addStringField(R.id.tvCarType, new StringExtractor<Cars>() {
        @Override
        public String getStringValue(Cars product, int position) {
            return "Car Type: " + product.Car_Type;
        }
    });
    dict.addStringField(R.id.tvCapacity, new StringExtractor<Cars>() {
        @Override
        public String getStringValue(Cars product, int position) {
            return "Capacity: " + product.Capacity;
        }
    });
    dict.addStringField(R.id.tvFuelType, new StringExtractor<Cars>() {
        @Override
        public String getStringValue(Cars product, int position) {
            return "Fuel Type: " + product.FuelType;
        }
    });
    dict.addStringField(R.id.tvPlateNumber, new StringExtractor<Cars>() {
        @Override
        public String getStringValue(Cars product, int position) {
            return "Plate Number: " + product.PlateNumber;
        }
    });
    dict.addStringField(R.id.tvPoster, new StringExtractor<Cars>() {
        @Override
        public String getStringValue(Cars product, int position) {
            return "Posted by: " + product.owner;
        }
    });
    dict.addStringField(R.id.tvPrice, new StringExtractor<Cars>() {
        @Override
        public String getStringValue(Cars product, int position) {
            return "Price: " + product.carPrice;
        }
    });
    dict.addStringField(R.id.tvFrom1, new StringExtractor<Cars>() {
        @Override
        public String getStringValue(Cars product, int position) {
            return "Range: " + product.rangeFrom+" ";
        }
    });
    dict.addStringField(R.id.tvTo1, new StringExtractor<Cars>() {
        @Override
        public String getStringValue(Cars product, int position) {
            return " " + product.rangeTo;
        }
    });
    dict.addStringField(R.id.tvDriver, new StringExtractor<Cars>() {
        @Override
        public String getStringValue(Cars product, int position) {
            return "Driver: " + product.carDriver;
        }
    });
    dict.addStringField(R.id.tvMaxDays, new StringExtractor<Cars>() {
        @Override
        public String getStringValue(Cars product, int position) {
            return "Max Days: " + product.carDays;
        }
    });
    dict.addStringField(R.id.tvDriverFirst, new StringExtractor<Cars>() {
        @Override
        public String getStringValue(Cars product, int position) {
            return " " + product.driverFirstName;
        }
    });
    dict.addStringField(R.id.tvDriverMiddle, new StringExtractor<Cars>() {
        @Override
        public String getStringValue(Cars product, int position) {
            return " " + product.driverMiddleName;
        }
    });
    dict.addStringField(R.id.tvDriverLast, new StringExtractor<Cars>() {
        @Override
        public String getStringValue(Cars product, int position) {
            return " " + product.driverLastName;
        }
    });
    dict.addStringField(R.id.tvOwnerContact, new StringExtractor<Cars>() {
        @Override
        public String getStringValue(Cars product, int position) {
            return " " + product.ownerContact;
        }
    });



    adapter = new FunDapter<>(
            getActivity(), carList, R.layout.layout_list, dict);

    lvCars.setAdapter(adapter);
    lvCars.setOnItemClickListener(this);

    if(swipeCar.isRefreshing()){
        swipeCar.setRefreshing(false);
    }
    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
}

@Override
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
    Cars selectedCars = carList.get(position);
    Intent in = new Intent(getActivity(), DetailActivity.class);
    in.putExtra("cars2", selectedCars);
    startActivity(in);
}
```

## DetailActivity

```
        final Cars Cars = (Cars)getIntent().getSerializableExtra("cars2");

try {
if (Cars != null) {

    tvDriver321.setText(Cars.carDriver);
    tvMaxDays.setText(Cars.carDays);
    tvCarModel.setText(Cars.Car_Model);
    tvCarType.setText( Cars.Car_Type);
    tvCapacity.setText(""+Cars.Capacity);
    tvFuelType.setText(Cars.FuelType);
    tvPlateNumber.setText(Cars.PlateNumber);
    tvPoster.setText(Cars.owner);
    tvPrice.setText(Cars.carPrice);
    tvCarID.setText(""+Cars.Car_No);
    tvFrom.setText(Cars.rangeFrom);
    tvTo.setText(Cars.rangeTo);
    tvDriver.setText(Cars.driverFirstName);
    tvDriverLast.setText(Cars.driverLastName);
    tvContact.setText(Cars.ownerContact);

    Log.d(TAG,Cars.Car_Model);

    ImageLoader.getInstance().displayImage(Cars.Image, ivImage);

}

}catch (Exception e){
    System.out.println("Error in details: " + e.toString());
}
```

## Cars.class

```
public class Cars implements Serializable {



@SerializedName("Car_No")
public int Car_No;

@SerializedName("Car_Model")
public String Car_Model;

@SerializedName("Car_Type")
public String Car_Type;

@SerializedName("Capacity")
public  int Capacity;

@SerializedName("Image")
public String Image;

@SerializedName("fuelType")
public String FuelType;

@SerializedName("carPlatenuNumber")
public String PlateNumber;

@SerializedName("owner")
public String owner;

@SerializedName("carPrice")
public String carPrice;

@SerializedName("resDate")
public String resDate;

@SerializedName("resTime")
public String resTime;

@SerializedName("resLocation")
public String resLocation;

@SerializedName("rangeFrom")
public String rangeFrom;

@SerializedName("rangeTo")
public String rangeTo;

@SerializedName("carDriver")
public String carDriver;

@SerializedName("carDays")
public String carDays;

@SerializedName("driverFirstName")
public String driverFirstName;

@SerializedName("driverMiddleName")
public String driverMiddleName;

@SerializedName("driverLastName")
public String driverLastName;

@SerializedName("ownerContact")
public String ownerContact;


}
```

Comment: Get a log after `Cars selectedCars = carList.get(position);`. Show me some values like position after clicked and its `selectedCars`

Comment: If you are only using Serializable to pass between activities, you should make `Cars` implement [`Parcelable`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Parcelable.html) instead. That's the recommended way to do it in Android and it always works just fine for me

Comment: @AmrAbed Serializable still work with this case. 'cos his variable doesn't contain any object which implement `Parcelable` or not compartitive with `Serializable`

Comment: @TruongHieu I know it should work. I am just saying that this is exactly what `Parcelable` should be used for

Comment: Solve this problem is different than find other way to do it.

Comment: @TruongHieu - I tried this `Log.d(TAG, carList.get(position).toString());` under the onClick and this what happened `D/com.example.kun.carkila.rentList: com.example.kun.carkila.Cars@4ec231cc` is this right? LOL

Comment: @JosephG `Log.i("joseph", position)` and `Log.i("joseph", carList.get(position).Car_Model)`

Comment: @TruongHieu - `01-13 16:48:03.305 16758-16758/com.example.kun.carkila I/joseph: 0` the `position` and `01-13 16:48:03.305 16758-16758/com.example.kun.carkila I/joseph: qwe123` the `Car Model` the `Car_Model` and that is the car model of what I pressed sir.

Comment: @TruongHieu - `com.example.kun.carkila.Cars@4ec23308` on the 2nd click this is what appearing

Comment: that is your log.d still exist. I have no idea about this. You may try ArmAbed solution.

Comment: post your manifest please

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
@Override
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
    Car selectedCars = carList.get(position);
    Intent in = new Intent(getActivity(), DetailActivity.class);
    in.putExtra("cars2", selectedCars);
    startActivity(in);
}
```

In other `Activity`:

```
final Car Cars = getIntent().getSerializableExtra("cars2");
```

Comment: His `carList` is a List object. So `carList.get(position)` will return Car object. You might wrong about it.

Comment: When I'm changing the `selectedCars` to int its not working sir.

Comment: It won't be `getIntExtra`, you didn't edit it completed :P